# Trying to create code that will allow data to be typed in one page excel record creating a report in 2nd page

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a tracking sheet (Sheet1), where information is tracked in one record and then using a button, "update" it transfer this information to "Sheet2" which will be a monthly report.

I have 8 columns on page 2 with headings.

Page one is where I enter my data in cells where my update button lies.

Here is my code I've derived using just one column:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim SerialNumber As String
Worksheets("Calibration Record").Select
SerialNumber = Range("E5")
Worksheets("Monthly Due Report").Select
Worksheets("Monthly Due Report").Range("A2").Select

If Worksheets("Monthly Due Report").Range("A2").Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
    Worksheets("Monthly Due Report").Range("A2").End(x1down).Select
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = SerialNumber

Worksheets("Calibration Record").Select
Worksheets("Calibration Record").Range("A2").Select
End Sub
```

I have also tried it with all 8 columns to no avail.

I was able to make it work one time with the code shown above.

When I entered data for the 2nd line of information it gave me the "Runtime error '1004'. Appliation-defined or object-defined error.

I've been working with this for nearly a month and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've even watched a video by Dinesh Kumar Takya on YouTube to no avail.

I've followed everything he did numerous times and I still am able to get it to work once but after that I get the run time errors.

Comment: You're only selecting ranges here- which sheet is which in your code? You call out "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" but I see named sheets in the code here.

Comment: sheet1 has the title of Calibration Record, sheet2 has the title Monthly Due Report.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry not enough point (any) to comment but pretty sure you have x1down not xlDown in that code snippet. Would work first time if that code isn't executed but then would throw an error. Looks like a typo to me.